# Django Beginner: Display value of RawQuerySet

Tags: python, django

I am using a RAW SQL query to get the record of each week's sale and then sum it up and show it on the web page. Here's my query:

```
sales = addCustomer.objects.raw("SELECT SUM(productPrice) FROM cms_addcustomer WHERE date <= %s and date >= %s", [startdate, weekDate])
```

Already using the datetime library to get the date and everything is working fine on this end.

However, when I try to display the result I get this message on my webpage:

```
Total Sales: Rs.<RawQuerySet: SELECT 
SUM(productPrice) FROM cms_addcustomer WHERE 
date <= 2020-07-29 and date >= 2020-07-23>
```

As also shown in this screenshot
[image: screenshot]

**I just want to display the sum of the Sales on my webpage but I am not sure how to do it.**

addCustomer Model:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
class addCustomer(models.Model):
 customerName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 productName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 productPrice = models.IntegerField()
 date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
 commission = models.IntegerField()
```

I have read most of the answers on Stack Overflow but I was unable to understand them as I am complete beginner. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add your `addCustomer` model to the question? You should be able to do this without using `raw()` and using `aggregate()` instead

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `.raw(..)` and not just the Django ORM?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have added the model to the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not sure how to do it. I tried using the aggregate with it but that's not working for me. Basically, I have three radio buttons that filter the result by a daily, weekly, and monthly basis.

I am not sure how to use the aggregate correctly and use the date conditions in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a query with [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total = addCustomer.objects.filter(
    date__range=(weekDate, startDate)
).aggregate(
    total_productprice=Sum('productPrice')
)['total_productprice']
```

here `total` will thus retrieve the sum of the `productPrice` values in the range.

For your `date` field, you might want to use a [**`db_index=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) to boost searching the records. Furthermore you might want to use [**`auto_now_add=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add), this will not only set the field value to the current date, but also make the field non-editable by default:

```
class addCustomer(models.Model):
    customerName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    productName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    productPrice = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    commission = models.IntegerField()
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `product_price` instead of <s>`productPrice`</s>.

Comment: I think the `date__range` should be the other way around based on the question, just incase this doesn't "work" for the OP

Comment: Thank you so much @WillemVanOnsem! This worked like a charm. I was stuck on this. Also, I would follow the snake_case pattern from now on. Your help is highly appreciated.

@IainShelvington Thank you for pointing that out. I got None as the result when using (startDate, weekDate) but after replacing it with (weekDate, startDate), I got the result.